# how to change colour of specific words in a powerpoint in python

Tags: python, format, powerpoint, python-pptx, textcolor

I am using python-pptx library of python to automate a powerpoint presentation that we are required to create on monthly basis as part of a report. Certain words in text of existing presentation are coloured red, green or yellow. I'd like to implement this using python-pptx library or any other method available but so far I don't see any way that I can use to achieve this. Please find below screenshot for reference and thanks in advance for help.

[image: individual Words coloured differently]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x80, 0x18, 0x18)
```

Furthermore, if you are coloring multiple words/sentences:

```
from pptx.util import Pt

p = tf.add_paragraph()
run = p.add_run()
blue = p.add_run()
blue.text = 'this is blue'
blue.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)
run.text = 'this is red'
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(178,34,34)
```

Python-pptx docs: [link](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html)

RGB colors: [link](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html)

Comment: This worked for me just fine, thank you. Unfortunately, the documentation was not simple enough for me.

Comment: @Anas you are basically creating text, customizing it's color then running it, some docs can be quite confusing so I understand. If my answer has solved your question, please do [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Thanks :0

Comment: yes the answer was able to help me. Thanks for the help. I have accepted it.